# Fatal error compiling: target level should be comprised in between '1.1' and '1.8' (or '5', '5.0', ..., '8' or '8.0') or cldc1.1: 11.0.11

Tags: java, spring, maven

While building maven project which has been upgraded from java 1.8 to java 11.0.11 . Getting the below error.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project XXX.XXX.XXX: Fatal error compiling: target level should be comprised in between '1.1' and '1.8' (or '5', '5.0', ..., '8' or '8.0') or cldc1.1: 11.0.11
```

**Configuration:**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <release>11</release>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Just use `11.0`. Patch version usually doesn't matter.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it will be helpful. @JohannesKuhn I've tried with 11.0 also but still getting same issue

Comment: Is this maven? Then try `1.11`. Because... maven.

Comment: Please add your full pom.xml

Comment: Maybe try with version 3.8.1 of the plugin. It seems 3.8.0 got published in July 2018, i.e. 2 months before Java 11 was released (September 2018).

Comment: @Thomas Even Maven 3.0.5 works with JDK 11... also the plugin. The error message implies something different. which does not correspond with the given pom snippet..

Comment: Are you by any chance still using Java 8 to run the build? What output does `mvn - version` produce (especially the "Java version" part)?

Comment: Java version is 11 when i execute the mvn -version command @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the configuration area of the plugin...

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: The OP is using it, the post is just badly formatted.

Comment: Yes but the error message which is posted shows a different behaviour...does not correspond to the error messge...

Comment: Also the old version supported the options see https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.0/compile-mojo.html